# After installing slurm 14.11,there is not any script in /etc//init.d/

Tags: linux, cluster

After installing the slurm 14.11,there should be a a slurm script in /etc/init.d/,but I did not find it in the directory,what's the reason?

Comment: I install it using the source code.And my OS is centOS6.6

Answer (score 2):

If you install slurm from source code, the init script is not installed by default.

You can find the init script in `etc/init.d.slurm` and `etc/init.d.slurmdbd` inside the source directory.

Just copy them to the /etc/init.d and add the services with:

`chkconfig --add slurm
chkconfig --add slurmdbd`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had thought no one would answer my question.